# Switching from desktop development to web-based development

Tags: web, web-applications, cloud

I was thinking recently about changing my main profile as a developer and I want some opinions and insights about this.

I don’t live in Silicon Valley, I’m in an eastern European country where the valley’s buzz arrives about 5 years later, if it does at all. Python, Rails, node.js is not as mainstream or “hip” at all, everything revolves around PHP, Java, .NET.

I’m not saying that we produce crappy code, there are many great developers, I’m just saying that technology-wise, we’re a little behind.

My experience is with C# desktop mainly, but I worked with PHP and Java as well, 2/3 part desktop applications. As of recently, I’m digging deep in JavaScript technologies and Python — and I really like it!

I decided that I want to shift towards web technologies primarily, involving technologies which can be transmitted to desktop area as well.

**For example:**

Recently I got a project which involved a desktop app. The customer doesn’t really care what technology I use, but I choose C# WinForms as I have most experience from it. However, this could be done easily with anything else and I was thinking that maybe there’s a solution for a JavaScript-based app, or something else, I don’t know.

My question is what languages do you guys suggest which can be applied to both desktop and web.

I was playing around with node.js and Python but not very familiar with the possibilities to be honest. I see the future in cloud applications and mobile development, so my decision is a strategical one.

Please omit the “if you like desktop development, stick with it”, because I like web development as well, I just want to shift to it primarily.

Comment: There's no right answer to this. The important switch is Winforms to Desktop. Technology stack look at the job market in your location and gamble. Whichever one you choose you will be using HTML(5) and javascript anyway. How much of them you have to know depends on how much support in the tech stack, but even then you are going to have to learn the DSL they are hiding the implementation behind. Trying to predict which flavour you should go for is something you should leave to Gartner numpties. It's no different to asking whether to learn C++, C#, Java etc in winforms

Comment: I might refine the question then. What are the possibilities if i want to know a web technology, but occasionally do a desktop project without switching to a completely different language? The new win8 based metro design enables html5 + js development as far as i know, but if we take linux into consideration, then this is not an option either. Is there anything like this?

Comment: Well you can do ECMA Script, Python and Ruby in .net. I'm not getting why switching language is some sort of major issue, if you can program in C#, you can program in anything, and it you are doing web based, you are delivering HTML,CSS and javascript, no matter which stack you use. It's not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing app that can be done as web app, but you just want it to sit on user desktop and work without Internet connection, then you should go web development IMHO

The main challenge will be packing web server application in a way that is easy for desktop user.

There are 2 solutions I know:

1. Package your web application with all dependencies into single Java EE .war file, and put it on desktop with simple Tomcat web server (this can be done with JRuby/warbler).
2. Alternative could be to create VMware Image with web server (web server will start in server start scripts, so user needs just to start the VMware instance).